# Getting Error SVN E175002 unexpected return value

Tags: svn, repository

When I am trying to read from the SVN repository, I am getting the following error:

```
svn: E175002: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) 
in response to REPORT request for '/!svn/vcc/default'
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: Dont know what was the reason i was getting this error for last one hour now everything is fine. can anyone tell why this error came?

Comment: There should be something in the server log.

Comment: Can you tell me more details what problem in server log?

Comment: Your web server does have some issue(which means that `500 Internal Server Error` response). The error log of your web server does very likely have some entries, about what went wrong. When you use apache, the default location for this logfile is `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Comment: got this error when I was not in VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This could be triggered by not giving your web server access to the repository. Try `chown -R apache:apache <path to svn repos>`.

Comment: Not likely if it was working before and went back to work again as mentioned in the OP comments.